# What's the difference between pass and continue in python

Tags: python, for-loop

My test shows that both `pass` and `continue` can be used equivalently to construct a empty `for`-loop for test purpose. Are there any difference between them?

Comment: Documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `pass` keyword is a "no-operation" keyword. It does exactly nothing. It's often used as a placeholder for code which will be added later:

```py
if response == "yes":
    pass  # add "yes" code later.
```

The `continue` keyword, on the other hand, is used to restart a loop at the control point, such as with:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
```

That loop will only output the odd numbers since `continue` returns to the loop control statement (`for`) for iterations where `i` is even.

Contrast that with the exact same code, but using `pass` in place of `continue`:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        pass
    print(i)
```

That loop prints *all* the numbers in the range, since `pass` does not return to the loop control statement for even (or any) values of `i`. It simply drops through to the `print` statement.

In terms of an *empty* `for` loop, you're correct that they're functionally identical. You can use either of:

```py
for i in range(10):
    pass
for i in range(10):
    continue
```

Comment: so we could use comment instead of pass right if it is placeholder

Comment: @The6thSense no, if you have an empty `for` loop with only a comment within it, Python will be confused because it looks for code inside a loop. That's why you need to use `pass` keyword even though it does nothing. Try running this and see the error: ```for i in range(10): # some comment``` (you will see `IndentationError: expected an indented block`). Then try replacing the comment with `pass` and it won't throw an error anymore

Comment: @nickang thanks for the info mate

Answer (score 3):

`pass` does nothing (no operation), while `continue` make control flow to continue to next cycle of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

If the loop contains only a single statement, a `pass` or `continue` won't make any difference. But if there are multiple statements, then it matters:

```
for item in my_list:
    pass
    print(item) #This will be executed

for item in my_list:
    continue
    print(item) #won't be executed
```

Basically, the pass statement do nothing, while the continue statement will restart the loop.

But in your case:

```
for item in my_list:
    pass
    #Since there's nothing after pass, the loop is finished.
for item in my_list:
    continue
    #You're restarting the loop
```

There difference is not very visible.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`continue` means "skip to the end of the loop body". If it's a `while` loop, the loop continues on to the loop test; if it's a `for` loop, the loop continues on to the next element of whatever it's iterating over.

`pass` does absolutely nothing. It exists because you have to have *something* in the body of an empty block statement, and `pass` is more readable than executing `1` or `None` as a statement for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This will lead to an infinite loop if you use `continue`:

```
i = 0
while i<1:
   continue  
   i = i + 1
   print i
```

because `continue` only goes to the next iteration. But `pass` will work for this case.

Answer (score 1):

`pass` and `continue` both work, but may create infinite loops.

For example, the following code will create infinite loop.

```
i = 0
while i<100:
 continue # replacing continue with pass still creates an infinite loop.
```

If you want to avoid this (perhaps you intend to modify `i` withe loop, but you haven't written the code yet), use `break`.